# BigInteger non-immutable alternative/workaround

Tags: java

In my game you have money. The money value is stored in a variable of type `long`.
The problem is that this variable max value is not enough.
So I wanted to change it to a `BigInteger`, but this is an immutable class
and I need to store and update this value in the same place.

Is there another class like `BigInteger` that is not immutable or a workaround?

Comment: Post your code/class and why you think it does not work.

Comment: BigInteger supports various operations (e.g. add, multiply substract), see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html). Can you add an example of what is not working?

Comment: `BigInteger` being immutable just means that you cannot change a given instance of it. You can still reassign the variable with a new value.

Comment: The max value of a long is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. Which means billions of billions. Are you really sure that's not enough to represent an amount of money? If a user has as much money, he won't even be able to tell how much he has.

Comment: actualy it would be enought and i guess i don't need to change from long to biginterger. i was testing my game by giving me way to much money

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `BigInteger` for this purpose and I don't understand how the immutability might affect the use case.

You can do all operations on a `BigInteger`. For example:

```
BigInteger a = BigInteger.valueOf(100);
a = a.add(BigInteger.valueOf(200));
BigInteger b = a.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(2));
```

The only thing that changes due to immutability is that you need to create a new object every time you have a value but you can overwrite your current object with that value. Also, immutability is less error prone in multithreaded cases.

Comment: But `BigInteger` can be used for values that `long` cannot accomodate.

Comment: That's exactly my point. The immutability of `BigInteger` is not affecting the usage at all.

Answer (score 0):

Java by default doesn't have a data type (keywords) that stores values more than the value of long.

There is an object type you can store values high as much as you want - as long as your system's RAM can handle it which was BigInteger and BigDecimal.

Unfortunately, there isn't a built-in class similar to `BigInteger` that isn't immutable. The only way you can change the value in a BigInteger object is reassigning it, which means creating an instance every time you wanted to change the value.

However, this may cost performance if you change the value many times in a short period of time. You can create a `String` variable that you can reassign it if there is a change and then at the end you can reassign the BigInteger object.

Short answer, no.